# C# function to cast multiple datarow values as null if dbnull is detected

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, datatable, datarow

My Linq-to-SQL program is returning quite a few values from my SQL Server database some of which the values can be null and others not.

If the `DataTable` column is cast as string, this is not an issue. However when it is cast as decimal, I get error messages stating decimal cannot be null.

What I need to find out is how I can handle these effectively whilst keeping my code neat.

```
// Create DataTable
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.add("Deal", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.add("Price", typeof(decimal) ?? typeof(DBNull));

// Create Linq Query
var query =
    from quer in table 
    select new  
    {
        quer.deal_id,
        quer.price 
    };
```

Here I create my datarows before inserting into the table:

```
var datarows = query.Select(r =>
{
    var row = dt.NewRow();
    row["Deal"] = r.deal_id;
    row["Price"] = r.price;
};
```

Now to ensure that my datarow can handle Nulls, I can just make it nullable but it's not necessary.

```
dt.Columns.add("Deal", typeof(string?));
```

But for the decimal field I have to do this:

```
if (r.price == DBNull.Value)
{
    row["Price"] = null;
}
```

Now I have to do about 50 of these `if` statement checks per table I'm designing. Can I just pass it to a function to do?

Comment: You cant do it like this dt.Columns.add("Price", typeof(decimal?));? and read it like decimal value = (row["Price"] as decimal?).GetValueOrDefault()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set your `DataColumn` to accept `DBNull` values:

```
// Create DataTable
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.add(new DataColumn( "Deal", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.add(new DataColumn( "Price", typeof(decimal)){AllowDBNull = true});

// Create Linq Query
var query =
    from quer in table 
    select new  
    {
        quer.deal_id,
        quer.price 
    };
```